# Can Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition be used as an embedded database?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I'm working with C# and I want to develop desktop application that use a database. The final purpose is to embed my database file so I can instal the application in every single computer.

My questions are :

1. Is Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition a viable solution for embedded database?
2. How to use it?
3. Can you give me some tutorials to deal with it?

Thank you, I'll really appreciate your answers.

Comment: This is a very broad question, too broad probably. "2. How to use it?" could fill a book chapter.

Answer (score 2):

"Yes"

Why? Because, like any good "embedded database", it doesn't require a separate installation. In addition, but not absolutely required, SQL Server CE runs in-process.

Other alternative include SQLite and Firebird (and many more); so the question is then, which database is right *for you*? (Which, ignoring a few technical differences, comes a good bit down to preference and preferred tooling ..)

For #2 and #3, please consult a book/tutorial/google *first*.